# Problem with regex fuzzy search with positive lookahead (AND) and {e=<3}

Tags: python-3.x, regex, fuzzy-search, positive-lookahead

I've a problem with the Python regex fuzzy search.

This is working:

```
import regex
s = '2991  Nixon Avenue Chattanooga Tennessee'
regex.search(r"(?msi)(?=.*\bnixon\b)(?=.*\bchattanooga\b)",s)
```

This is not working (removed a `t` from `Chattanooga`): result `None`

```
import regex
s = '2991  Nixon Avenue Chatanooga Tennessee'
regex.search(r"(?msie)(?=.*\bnixon\b)(?=.*\bchattanooga\b){e=<3}",s)
```

What am I doing wrong here?
It looks like it's something with the positive lookahead and the word bounderies.

**Note:** This is just a simple example to get it working. I reality is the part of a more complex job.

Aside, do i need to specify the fuzziness per regex item (`nixon`, `chattanooga`) or is it possible to do it for both at the same time e.g. `((?=.*\bnixon)(?=.*\bchattanooga\b)){e=<3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was applying the fuzziness to the lookahead itself instead of to its
contents.

If it's "Chattanooga" that's fuzzy, do:

```
regex.search(r"(?msie)(?=.*\bnixon\b)(?=.*\b(?:chattanooga){e<=3}\b)",s)
```